# Sort tables based on td class value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to sort multiple `td` elements in one or more `tr` based on the class of each `td`. All these are in a multiple `table` with classname="hosts". For now i'm trying to just sort a single table but my jQuery skills aren't good (read really bad). I've searched on StackOverflow for similar questions but couldn't find a solution.

Example:

```
<table class="hosts"
  ><tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.38"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012344.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.18"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012345.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.88"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012399.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.48"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012334.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.58"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012244.lan.local</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr
      ><td class="FAILED" title="192.168.0.68"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022666.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.98"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022333.lan.local</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The result i would like to get is (for example sorted from passed to failed):

```
<table class="hosts"
  ><tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.38"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012344.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.88"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012399.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.48"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012334.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.98"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022333.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.18"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012345.lan.local</a></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.58"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012244.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="FAILED" title="192.168.0.68"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022666.lan.local</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(".hosts tbody tr").sort(function(a, b) {
  return $("td", b).attr("class") < $("td", a).attr("class") ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('.hosts tbody');
```

I've created a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noekk/mypsk2gu/1/)** with above code and some jQuery i've found on here which only swaps the entire table. I understand why this is happening, but don't know where to start to actually fix this.

In the end i would like to format multiple tables with the same class in the same way. But that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `sort()` logic is looking at the `tr` elements themselves instead of looping through the `tr` and sorting the `td` within them.

In addition the order you're trying to create using the class values is not alphabetical. As such you can use an array of the classnames in the order you want to sort them in to  and use `indexOf()` in the comparison. Try this:

```js
var classOrder = ['PASSED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED']

$(".hosts tbody tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find('td').sort(function(a, b) {
    return classOrder.indexOf(a.className) > classOrder.indexOf(b.className) ? 1 : -1;
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```css
.hostip {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.hosts td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.hosts .PASSED {
  background-color: #4CAE4C;
  color: white;
}

.hosts .FAILED {
  background-color: #D43F3A;
  color: white;
}

.hosts .WARNING {
  background-color: #FDC431;
  color: black;
}

.hosts .ERROR {
  background-color: #EE9336;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="hosts">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.38"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012344.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.18"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012345.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.88"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012399.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.48"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012334.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="WARNING" title="192.168.0.58"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV012244.lan.local</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FAILED" title="192.168.0.68"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022666.lan.local</a></td>
      <td class="PASSED" title="192.168.0.98"><a class="hostip" href="#">SRV022333.lan.local</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems promising, i know the classes aren't alphabetical but is that also the reason why it wouldn't sort at all? Your snippet fetches all `tr` that are preceeded by a `tbody` owned by a `table` class=hosts and proceeds to sorts them per `tr`. 

Also i'm trying to show PASSED first, followed by WARNING etc. So when i have six hosts with PASSED, show five on the first row followed by one on the second and then hosts with WARNING. What's the best way of doing this? 

Do you have any recommendations to read besides jQuery documentation?